# How to resolve TypeScript compiler error TS2339: Property 'errorValue' does not exist on type {} in my Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I have written a function in a component to handle when errors are returned from a Rest Service and determine what error message should be shown to the user, the method takes an error object (this is custom data with a specific structure from the rest service) as an argument, drills sown to find the relevant content and then using a switch statement sends a JSON key that is used by an i18n service, it is below (I know it isn't the greatest)

```
private myErrorHandler(err: any): string {
    // Why doesn't typescript support null-conditional?
    if (err.error && err.error.errors && err.error.errors[0] && err.error.errors[0].error) {
      const errorMsg = err.error.errors[0].error;
      const errorValue = err.error.errors[0].value;
      const translationArgs: any = {errorValue: null};
      let correctMsg;

      if (errorValue) {
        translationArgs.errorValue = errorValue; // this line gives me the TypeScript compiler error TS2339: Property 'errorValue' does not exist on type {}
      }

      switch (errorMsg) {
        case 'not_unique': {
          correctMsg = errorValue ? 'common.validation.not_unique_value' : 'common.validation.not_unique';
          break;
        }
        default: {
          correctMsg = 'common.messages.global_error';
          break;
        }
      }
      return this.localizationService.translate(correctMsg, translationArgs as any);
    }
    return this.localizationService.translate('common.messages.global_error');
  }
```

My problem is that sometimes I wish to interpolate some of the returned error data into the returned message as an argument, the method above allows me to do this but the way I set this, like so, raises a TypeScript compiler error:

```
if (errorValue) {
            translationArgs.errorValue = errorValue;
}
```

How can I prevent this linting error? I thought by giving the object const translationArgs a errorValue property and assigning this to null would be enough... but I was / am wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

I am also aware that the method / function is a little ugly, so any comments on that are appreciated too.

(as requested) This is the content of my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceRoot": "frontend",
    "rootDir": "frontend",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha",
      "chai",
      "chai-as-promised",
      "aws-sdk",
      "q",
      "sinon",
      "file-saver"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "frontend/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    ".git",
    ".idea",
    "config",
    "dist",
    "e2e_tests",
    "gulp",
    "node_modules",
    "reports",
    "server",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "debug": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your tslint config ?

Comment: This is not a TSLint issue, but a TypeScript compiler error. What are your tsconfig.json settings?

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to create an interface for the const object?

Comment: `err.error.errors[0].error` gave me a headache.

Comment: I removed it using the try/catch from Vayrex's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not any problems with you tslint config. Here is little refactored version.

```
myErrorHandler(err: any): string {

  let error: any;
  try {
    error = err.error.errors[0];
  } catch (e) {
    return this.localizationService.translate('common.messages.global_error');
  }

  const errorMsg = error.error;
  const errorValue = error.value;
  const translationArgs = {errorValue: null};
  let correctMsg;

  if (errorValue) {
    translationArgs.errorValue = errorValue;
  }

  switch (errorMsg) {
    case 'not_unique': {
      correctMsg = errorValue ? 'common.validation.not_unique_value' : 'common.validation.not_unique';
      break;
    }
    default: {
      correctMsg = 'common.messages.global_error';
      break;
    }
  }
  return this.localizationService.translate(correctMsg, translationArgs as any);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a gorgeous solution but you can always do

```
(translationArgs as any).errorValue = errorValue;
```

or provide a better type than `any` that isn't `{}`.

Comment: Equivalent syntax (merely for completeness): `<any>translationArgs.errorValue = errorValue;` though I do personally prefer to `as` construct.